# Aspose Cell .net core: Some text is cut off on linux host

Tags: asp.net-core, aspose, aspose-cells

I got an issue when develop an export feature using aspose on .net core platform. The issue is that some of the rows data exported as PDF is being cut-off.

I tried on my local environment (windows) there are no issue. The result is as good as I expected.

But when I publish the code into host environment (linux) the result seems off.

**My local result (windows)**

[image]

**My hosted result (linux)**

[image]

**Here  is piece of code that I am using to generate the file**

```
public FileData ExportToFile(DataTable data, string format, string query)
    {
        var workbook = new Workbook();
        var style = workbook.CreateStyle();
        workbook.DefaultStyle = style;

        var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        AutoFitterOptions oAutoFitterOptions = new AutoFitterOptions { AutoFitMergedCells = true, OnlyAuto = true };

        data = _RemoveFormat(data); // Parse all data to String
        
        /**/
        
        sheet.PageSetup.Orientation = PageOrientationType.Landscape;
        
        PdfSaveOptions pdfSaveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions();
        pdfSaveOptions.AllColumnsInOnePagePerSheet = true;
        sheet.AutoFitRows(oAutoFitterOptions);
        sheet.AutoFitColumns(oAutoFitterOptions);
        
        workbook.Save(stream, pdfSaveOptions);
        
        /**/
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your issue might be related to missing (installed) fonts (in hosted environment) on your end. By the way, what is your display scale settings for linux (os)? Please make sure display scale settings to 100% when executing the code. Also, please refer to your thread (https://forum.aspose.com/t/autofit-row-not-fit-in-linux-hosted-environment/215450) and follow up there.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with Aspose support. I found out that the differences caused by that missing font from my Hosted Server (linux). So I need to install it on the server to get both document have the same style.

In my case, the my app was hosted in kubernetes cluster, so I need to add this line of commands in the `dockerfile`

```
RUN echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        fontconfig \
        ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```